# Permissions granted, still www-data cannot write files in folder

Tags: linux, digital-ocean, apache2.4

I have set up an Ubuntu server on Digital Ocean. Following are the config details:

Ubuntu version : Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Apache version : Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

I am trying to run a php script through browser which will need to create a file in the directory . I keep getting the following permission denied message in the /var/log/apache2/error.log file `fopen(<folder_to_write>): failed to open stream: Permission denied in test_write.php`

I discovered that the user www-data (apache2 user) is having a permission issue. I changed the owner of the folder  as follows : 
`chown -R www-data:www-data folder_to_write`
and then 
`chmod 2775 folder_to_write`

This did not work.

Finally, I tried the last option. I changed the directory permission to `sudo chmod -R 777 folder_to_write` hoping to get some lead. However, despite giving this full access permission, I got the permission denied message.

Has anyone experienced any such issue earlier? Not sure what I am doing wrong. I tried the same steps with another user and that seems to be working fine.

I appreciate your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: can you double check if the www-data user has execute access on each and every folder in the folder nest? So, if you need to write into folder C in a nest A/B/C, make sure that it can execute (x) on each and every folder, A, B and C

Comment: Thank you @Maurizio. The folder does have recursive exeucte rights. With the same permissions, another user from the same group is able to create the file. Its only the www-data user  (which also belongs to the same group) that is not able to create a file.

Answer (score 0):

fopen(): failed to open stream:
It seems not able to find directory folder_to_write , Please check your absolute directory path if that's configured right for writing to a file.

Comment: Thank you @sahil. Yes, the path is present. I try this with another user and it works just fine. Only with www-data its giving this problem.